# get an object of listiview from onclick listener in adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hi I have a `listview` with its adapter and object class, there is a button in every listview position and I have a clicklistener in the adapter, but when I click on my `button` in the `listview` it returns the last item position.

here is my adapter:

```
public class comentario_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<comentario_obj> items;
    private Context mContext;
    comentario_obj prod;
    ImageButton correcta;
    boolean marcada = false;
    View vi;
    public comentario_adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<comentario_obj> items, Context context) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi=convertView;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comentario_adapter, null);
        }

        prod = items.get(position);

        TextView title_coment = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_coment);
        ImageButton voteup= (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.voteup);
        ImageButton votedown= (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.votedown);
        title_coment.setText(prod.getTitulo());

        ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.correcta);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mContext instanceof verPregunta_class){
                    ((verPregunta_class) mContext).MyMethod();
                        //NEED THE TITLE OF LISTVIEW POSITION CLICKED
                }
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }
    public interface IMethodCaller{
        void MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: naive way: make `prod` local final or use View.Tag ... also use google, asked baziilion times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782868/android-removing-item-from-listview-is-not-working-properly

Comment: yes but what have I to do with that tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can create in your OnCreate, for example, a method setOnItemClickListener for your listview and inside, ask for the position of the item in your items array. For example,

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {  

        String titulo = array.get(pos).getTitulo();
}
```

Hope it helps

Bye
    });

Comment: Mmm the same idea should works inside the adapter. Did you try?

Comment: But you have the position, so in theory you can do items.get(post).getTitulo() not?

Comment: yes but that throws ´java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0´

Comment: I think that the problem is in getView. Try to do it like here http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 and try again items.get(post).getTitulo(). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found the solution with `setTag`:

```
public class comentario_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<comentario_obj> items;
    private Context mContext;
    comentario_obj prod;
    ImageButton correcta;
    boolean marcada = false;
    View vi;
    public comentario_adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<comentario_obj> items, Context context) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi=convertView;

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comentario_adapter, null);
        }

        prod = items.get(position);

        TextView title_coment = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_coment);
        ImageButton voteup= (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.voteup);
        ImageButton votedown= (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.votedown);
        title_coment.setText(prod.getTitulo());

        final ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.correcta);
        **btn.setTag(prod.getId());**
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mContext instanceof verPregunta_class){
                    ((verPregunta_class) mContext).MyMethod();
                        **String title = (String) v.getTag();**
                }
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }
    public interface IMethodCaller{
        void MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Thanks to all!